# A convolution of prob. measures is also a prob. measure.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mu,\nu$ be two probability measures on $(\Omega=\mathbb{Z},\sigma=2^{\mathbb{Z}})$. Then the convolution of $\mu *\nu$ is defined as the probability measure on $(\Omega=\mathbb{Z},\sigma=2^{\mathbb{Z}})$,

$$ (\mu *\nu)(\{n\})=\sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}}\mu(\{m\})\nu(\{n-m\})$$.

How to prove that this defines in fact a prob. measure?

For that purpose I'm thinking of using the following theorem:

> (Extension theorem) Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a semi-ring, and let
>   $\mu:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be an additive,
>   $\sigma$-subadditive, and $\sigma$-finite set function with
>   $\mu(\emptyset)=0$. Then there is a unique $\sigma$-finite measure
>   $\tilde \mu :\sigma (\mathcal{A}) \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ such that
>   $\tilde \mu(A)=\mu(A) \forall_{A \in \mathcal{A}}$.

$\mathcal{A}=\{\{n\}:n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a semi-ring, and with sigma-algebra $2^\mathbb{Z}$.

I don't see how to prove that $\mu *\nu$ is additive... since it's not defined for $\{n,k\}$. Maybe it's additive precisely because only sets $\{n\} \in \mathcal{A}$

Also, after applying the theorem I need to prove that $(\mu *\nu)(\mathbb{Z})=1$. For this I've done $(\mu *\nu)(\mathbb{Z})=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} (\mu *\nu)(\{n\})=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} \sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}}\mu(\{m\})\nu(\{n-m\})$ $=\sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}}\mu(\{m\}) \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}\nu(\{n-m\})=\sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}}\mu(\{m\})=1$

The problem here, is why could I interchange the infinite sums? If I had $\sum_n \sum_m \mu(\{m\})\nu(\{n-m\})<\infty$ then I could interchange them...

Comment: When the terms are nonnegative one can **always** interchange the sums, whether the result is finite or not. This is called Fubini theorem for series.

Comment: The fact you are thinking about any extension theorem suggests you are over-complicating this - we have a countable discrete space, so we only need to consider singletons. All you need to prove is $\sum_n\mu*\nu(\{n\})=1$. As Did points out, interchanging sums is always allowed for series of nonnegative numbers, so you are done.

Comment: @Did thanks for the helpful comment.

Comment: @Jason, then, how do you prove that the convolution, the way it's defined, gives a measure?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is a measure on $(X,2^X)$ with $X$ countable, then $\lambda(A)=\sum_{x\in A}\lambda(\{x\})$ for any $A\subseteq X$. Conversely, given a function $\lambda:X\to[0,\infty]$, we can define a measure (which in an abuse of notation I will also call $\lambda$) by $\lambda(A):=\sum_{x\in A}\lambda(x)$ (note that an empty sum is zero by convention). Countable additivity is automatic. So all you need to do for countable spaces is verify nonnegativity, which is usually obvious. If you want a probability measure, the sum must be $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For probability measures on $\mathbb{Z}$, it's not necessary to use the extension theorem you quote.  Any function $p : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ such that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} p(n) = 1$ defines a probability measure via $p(A) = \sum_{j \in A} p(j)$.  That this is well-defined, first of all, follows from the fact that bounded non-decreasing sequences of real numbers always have finite limits.

Next, I'll check that this construction is, in fact, countably additive.  Suppose $\{A_{1},A_{2},\dots,\}$ is a disjoint collection of subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $A = \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_{n}$.  Fix $N \in \mathbb{N}$. 
 Then if we let $(b_{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ denote an enumeration of $A_{1} \cup \dots \cup A_{N}$, then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j \in A} p(j) &\geq \sum_{k =1}^{\infty} p(b_{k}) \\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} p(b_{k}) \left(1_{A_{1}}(b_{k}) + 1_{A_{2}}(b_{k}) + \dots + 1_{A_{N}}(b_{k})\right) \\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^{N} \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} p(b_{k}) 1_{A_{n}}(b_{k}) \\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^{N} \sum_{j \in A_{n}} p(j)
\end{align*}
and, thus, $\sum_{j \in A} p(j) \geq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} p(A_{n})$.  Note that here I've used the fact that series of non-negative terms are unconditionally convergent: the limit is independent of the order of summation.

On the other hand, arranging the elements of $A$ in a sequence $(a_{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$, we have
$$\sum_{j \in A} p(j) = \lim_{L \to \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^{L} p(a_{k})$$
and $\sum_{k = 1}^{L} p(a_{k}) \leq \sum_{n = 1}^{M} p(A_{n})$ for some $M = M(L)$ depending on $L$.  Since $\sum_{n = 1}^{M} p(A_{n}) \leq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} p(A_{n})$, we find
$$\sum_{j \in A} p(j) \leq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} p(A_{n}),$$
proving countable additivity.

If you have seen a bit more measure theory, then an alternative way to construct the measure $p$ is to distinguish between the function $p : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ and the measure, let's call it $\lambda_{p}$.  For this construction, you need to know about the counting measure $c$ on $\mathbb{Z}$.  Note that $\sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} p(j) = 1$ is just the same thing as $p \in L^{1}(\mathbb{Z},c)$ (by non-negativity of $p$).  Thus, the formula 
$$\lambda_{p}(A) = \int_{A} p(\xi) c(d \xi) = \sum_{j \in A} p(j)$$
defines a measure on $2^{\mathbb{Z}}$.  I only mention this because you may have seen this construction before and, at any rate, it comes up quite a lot (esp. in probability theory).

As a commenter already mentioned, that $p = \mu * \nu$ satisfies $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} p(n) = 1$ follows from the Fubini-Tonelli Theorem (whether you call it Fubini or Tonelli depending on taste/culture).

Comment: Thanks fourierwho! ;)